# jQuery fix for the iOS viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, viewport

Is there a way to convert the script for fixing the viewport into jQuery. Now the script is working parallel with jQuery script, and don't know how it going to conflict with jQuery.

The script is:

```
// Rewritten version
// By @mathias, @cheeaun and @jdalton

(function(doc) {

var addEvent = 'addEventListener',
type = 'gesturestart',
qsa = 'querySelectorAll',
scales = [1, 1],
meta = qsa in doc ? doc[qsa]('meta[name=viewport]') : [];

function fix() {
meta.content = 'width=device-width,minimum-scale=' + scales[0] + ',maximum-scale=' + scales[1];
doc.removeEventListener(type, fix, true);
}

if ((meta = meta[meta.length - 1]) && addEvent in doc) {
fix();
scales = [.25, 1.6];
doc[addEvent](type, fix, true);
}

}(document));
```

Source: http://www.blog.highub.com/mobile-2/a-fix-for-iphone-viewport-scale-bug/

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to worry about this conflicting with jQuery. It won't.

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be a conflict.  If I add dynamic text to a page with jQuery, the viewport bug is no longer fixed.  If I remove the reference to jquery.min.js, the bug is also removed.  Here are two pages which feature a horizontally-scrolling image.  The first page has the viewport bug fix, and uses a static caption for the image.  The bug is fixed.  The second page also uses the viewport bug fix, but it relies on jQuery to produce dynamic, fading text for the caption, and in this case the bug is not fixed...

http://mauitradewinds.com/test/view.htm  -- bug is fixed.

http://mauitradewinds.com/test/test.htm  -- bug is not fixed.

So I think the original poster's concern may be valid.